# which adb command to Delete gmail account from a device

Tags: adb, google-account

Can anyone pls suggest me which adb command i may use to delete gmail account from a device. I can add account through below command but can't delete any account.

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.ADD_ACCOUNT_SETTINGS
```